# Passing varargs in a secondary constructor

Tags: scala, constructor, variadic-functions

I have a class with a constructor which consists of a Charset and a vararg of type String.  I want a convenience constructor with just the vararg that will call the main constructor with a the defaultCharset and the vararg.

```
class StringMessage(charset: Charset, frames: String*) {
  def this(frames: String*) = this(Charset.defaultCharset, frames)
}
```

Unfortunately the class I have shown gives two errors:

```
called constructor's definition must precede calling constructor's definition
```

and

```
overloaded method constructor StringMessage with alternatives:
  (frames: String*)mypackage.StringMessage <and>
  (charset: java.nio.charset.Charset,frames: String*)mypackage.StringMessage
 cannot be applied to (java.nio.charset.Charset, String*)
  def this(frames: String*) = this(Charset.defaultCharset, frames)
                              ^
```

What is the best way to model this type of situation?

Comment: Is there a place to vote for unhelpful compiler messages?  I don't see the first error; and in 2.10, the second message is improved to "cannot be applied to (java.nio.charset.Charset, Seq[String])", so you can see the Seq.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do believe that `:_*` will work

```
class StringMessage(charset: Charset, frames: String*) {
  def this(frames: String*) = this(Charset.defaultCharset, frames: _*)
}
```

It instructs compiler to expand Seq, so it would look like you wrote:

```
this(Charset.defaultCharset, frames(0), frames(1), ....
```